# Typo3 version 8 Could not access remote resource http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz

Tags: curl, typo3, typo3-8.x

I can curl to https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz. although the message does say that there is a problem with the ssl certificate. So I know that there is no firewall rule preventing me contacting the url.

However, from the Typo3 back end I am unable to update the extensions list nor can I download any extensions.

I have curl set for downloads in the BackEnd.

I am on a 1&1 shared linux server. So have limited control over the environment.

I know that others have sought solutions to this but no solution has been successful for me as yet - and very few solutions have actually been provided.

**Question**

> How can I configure Typo3 to download from the repository?

Comment: I had the same problem this week on a managed 1&1 linux server. I found out, that 1&1 still use Debian 6 for some of their managed linux servers. According to the 1&1 support, they will update those old Debian 6 servers "soon"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is probably no real solution for your problem, but as I had the same problem on a 1&1 shared hosting server. I wrote to their support and got a reply after some days where they told me, that they have imported the CA certificate into the local certificate store. Now TER update in extension manager works fine again. Maybe 1&1 did roll out the CA certificate to all their "old" Debian system, so you should check if you are able to update extensions now.

Answer (score 3):

We are using an SSL certificate that is signed by a CA that is not trusted by older OSes (e.g. Debian Squeeze). This change became active on repositories.typo3.org on April 2nd. See [here](https://mobile.twitter.com/TYPO3server/status/704673020556787713), [here](https://mobile.twitter.com/TYPO3server/status/704674321566973952) and [here](https://mobile.twitter.com/TYPO3server/status/716335663587717123).